# Git:hide some plain text when push to github

Tags: git, github

I want to share a project on Github. But when I wanted to push the repository to github, I found a big security problem that I do not want to show my MySQL password and Hash salt to others. Do you guys have any ideas on hide these plain text when I push it to Github? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a hardcoded hash salt somewhere in your source code? What do you use that salt for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only and best option is not to store passwords in git.

Be careful because simply removing the file (`git rm all_my_passwords.txt`) won't be enough since the file will be accessible through history.

You should do two things now:

- if you have already pushed, change password and hash salt because they are compromised
- remove such data from the repository following [this GitHub article](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/)

Comment: But I do not think it is enough for I do not want to remove the whole file.Can I replace the password, hash salt etc to `*****` (and in git history as well)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to clean up your full history first. Use `git filter-branch` to replace your password and salt in your files before you push this thing to GitHub.